# Timezone and DST calculation in date/time libraries

Tags: date, datetime, timezone, dst, luxon

I am using specifically Luxon.  However this question applies to all date/time libraries.

What happens if a country (say the USA) decides to remain in DST the whole year?  To the point, libraries must contain a list of timezones and DST dates.  If DST changes for a country, does a new version of the library need to be published with the updated DST values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the library.

Some libraries bundle their own time zone data and needed to be updated regularly to receive such updates.  Examples include:

- [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) (JavaScript)
- [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) (Python)
- [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (Java)
- [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) (.NET)
- [TimezoneDB](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) (PHP)
- [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) (C/C++ & Java)

Other libraries take their time zone data from from the host environment they run within, which might in-turn take their time zone data from a library, or from the host OS.  Examples include:

- [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) (JavaScript), which uses `Intl`, which is most commonly implemented via ICU, which is distributed by the browser (or Node.js)
- [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) (built-in to Python), which uses the host OS time zone data if available, or the python `tzdata` package if not.
- [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (built-in to Java), which uses the time zone data distributed with the Java Runtime
- [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo) (built-in to .NET), which uses the time zone data from the host operating system

*These lists are not intended to be comprehensive.*

The ultimate source of the data is usually the [IANA TZ Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). All libraries that ship their own time zone data derive it from there.

However, Microsoft also still maintains [time zone data for Windows](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/daylight-saving-time-time-zone/bg-p/DSTBlog) separately.  It is still used by .NET on Windows platforms, and other older Windows technologies such as Win32 APIs.

Comment: Thank you @MattJohnson-Pint, this answer throughly answers the question across many platforms and libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily a new library but yes, at least a new database:  https://www.iana.org/time-zones.

IANA isn't the only timezone database, but it is probably the most widely used.  And it gets updated several times a year.  There were 7 updates last year (2022).

Answer (score 2):

No. Luxon's sense of when time zone's have DSTs doesn't come from its own data file; it comes from the JS runtime (the browser, or Node), which exposes them through the Intl API. The Intl API, in turn, uses the TZ rules from the ICU data bundled with the runtime. So when the browser (or other JS host) updates, Luxon gets those new rules.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand where the data is coming from.  I poked around node_modues/luxon last night and found nothing.  Thank you for making this clear.

Comment: Intl usually uses ICU, which bundles its own data.  Some OSs provide an ICU implementation, but many browsers (Chrome, etc.) ship ICU and time zone data internally.  That's probably a good thing, as browsers often self-update faster than OS-level updates can be applied.

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson-Pint. I updated the answer to reflect that clarification.